# Git filter-branch with index-filter does not work and remove directories as expected

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

Structure of Git repo foo in master branch

```
foo/refs/a.txt  
foo/bar/refs/b.txt
```

In other branches `refs/` might be in lots of other places

#### Goal

To remove all instances of the directory refs (and their content) from Git (history)
Environment: Windows 7 using Git Bash

#### Removing refs (Git not involved, tried this just to see that it works by itself)

```
find . -name refs -depth -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Success, all `refs/` and their content are removed (If I don't use `-depth`, find will report an error that the dirs don't exists even though they were removed correctly).

#### Removing refs from Git

```bash
git filter-branch --index-filter \
'find . -name refs -depth -exec git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch {} \;' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

[image: Removing directory refs from Git by rewriting the Git history]

As can be seen in the picture (think of `temp/a` as `temp/foo`) the command runs through and rewrites all commits but no `refs/` are removed so somehow the output of the find is not returned to `filter-branch --index-filter` as expected.

Similar things seem to work for others.
What am I missing?

PS. Yes I've read hundreds of posts, articles etc for hours and hours about this but it doesn't work for me anyway.

Comment: And with a ' ` | xargs -d'\n' ...` ', would that work better?  As in `git filter-branch --index-filter 'find . -name refs -depth | xargs -d '\n' git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

Comment: @VonC Then I get Rewrite a859284abcb08346f280f8ea8f64aff99857a47e (1/11)xargs: invalid option -- d

Comment: right the msysgit `xargs` is an old 4.1 from 2004 instead of a 4.4 from 2009: no `--delim` option back then. You can try without the delimiter, but I fear it takes the all `find` result as *one* line...

Comment: Or define an alias using perl: http://serverfault.com/a/127915/783 or try using a while read LINE: http://serverfault.com/a/128422/783 (not sure if it can work)

Comment: @VonC Do you have an example of how that could be written with a while read LINE? Also, how would you call such a script from git filter-branch --index-filter so it returns a so called <command> (as its called in man page http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html)?

Comment: Definitely feels like a windows/mysysgit issue.  Any chance you've got access to a linux/mac box somewhere that you could clone the repo to and try the command on?  Since this is a one time command maybe that'd be OK.

Comment: @TedNaleid good question. I'll have to try that tomorrow.

Comment: @TedNaleid I just tried in OS X 10.8.2. Same problem with both the exec and the xargs options.

Comment: I'd try putting the command in a shell script and executing that, I'd also pipe the output to a file with the `tee` command so you might get some insight into what's happening or if there's some error that's getting thrown.

Comment: @TedNaleid I'm not sure how to do that. I didn't find a solution to this yet but solved it partly by running something simliar to git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -f --cached --ignore-unmatch *.zip && git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch refs' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all   (plus about 15 other file extensions and relative paths)  I ended up removing at least 95% of what I wanted.

Comment: @riper I updated my answer, because apparently I was totally wrong about the index filter only working with Git commands. It looks like it works with non-Git commands too...as long as they have access to and modify the index file? I'm not sure. Still definitely an open question.

Comment: @riper hey, by the way, are you literally trying to remove all directories named `refs/`? Because if you are, Git actually stores all of its references under `.git/refs/` in non-bare repositories, in the working copy root...so the command `find . -name refs -depth` will actually dig up those directories too.

Answer (score 6):

### Update

Although my old answer apparently helped the original poster partially solve his problem, it appears that I may not actually be correct that the `--index-filter` only works with Git commands, because in the [documentation for `git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_examples), it gives an example of the filter being used with non-Git shell commands, in addition to Git commands:

```bash
git filter-branch --index-filter \
        'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&newsubdir/-" |
                GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
                        git update-index --index-info &&
         mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
```

It may just be the case that if you're going to use non-Git commands with `--index-filter`, then they *have* to operate on the repository's index, as shown in the above example from the documentation.

So basically, *I'm not sure why* the original poster's original index filter didn't work, but it might be the case that he was trying to access a part of the repository that the index filter doesn't allow access to, or that whatever non-Git command he was using didn't actually modify the index.

Also, [as I point out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837878/git-filter-branch-index-filter-not-working-does-not-remove-directories#comment38710792_13837878),

> Git actually stores all of its references under `.git/refs/` in non-bare repositories, in the working copy root...so the command `find . -name refs -depth` will actually dig up those directories too.

So maybe that's causing something to go horribly wrong during the filter-branch?

### Old Answer

I think the problem might be that you're trying to use non-Git shell tools with the `filter-branch --index-filter` option instead of the `--tree-filter` option:

```bash
git filter-branch --index-filter \
'find . -name refs -depth -exec git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch {} \;' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Unlike `--tree-filter`, which checks out a new working directory for each commit and runs the passed shell script on it, `--index-filter` only operates on the index file of a Git repo itself (it doesn't check out a working copy to operate on)...so only Git commands will work with it.

That's probably why you had better luck with this, because it passed Git commands to `filter-branch --index-filter`:

```bash
git filter-branch --index-filter \
'git rm -f --cached --ignore-unmatch *.zip && \
 git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch refs' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

This is the documentation for [git-filter-branch(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) `--tree-filter`:

> This is the filter for rewriting the tree and its contents. The argument is evaluated in shell with the working directory set to the root of the checked out tree.

and this is the documentation for `--index-filter` (emphasis mine):

> This is the filter for rewriting the index. ***It is similar to the tree filter but does not check out the tree***, which makes it much faster. Frequently used with `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch ...`, see EXAMPLES below. For hairy cases, see [git-update-index(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html).

Comment: One problem with the original poster's original index filter is that the filter tries to examine the working copy (with `find`) even though the index-filter doesn't check out the tree associated with each commit. So, any file that is not present in the latest commit will also not be found for earlier commits.